# angular seprate id and other querystring params

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I ma having this URL:
http://localhost:53096/autochangecompany/2?invoiceId=2933&action=approve&usertype=primary

I want to get the 2 as ID and other querystring params BUT i am unable to get it from route.params

```
this.invoiceAction = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['action'] || '';
this.invoiceId = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['invoiceId'] || '';
this.userType = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['usertype'] || '';
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
  this.companyId = +params['id']; 
});
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

you need to write id in routing .ts file.

e.g. path: '.../:id'